# How to select each model which has the maximum value of an attribute for any given value of another attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Work` model with a `video_id`, a `user_id` and some other simple fields. I need to display the last 12 works on the page, but only take 1 per user. Currently I'm trying to do it like this:

```
 def self.latest_works_one_per_user(video_id=nil)
   scope = self.includes(:user, :video)
   scope = video_id ? scope.where(video_id: video_id) : scope.where.not(video_id: nil)
   scope = scope.order(created_at: :desc)
   user_ids = works = []
   scope.each do |work|
     next if user_ids.include? work.user_id
     user_ids << work.user_id
     works << work
     break if works.size == 12
   end
   works
 end
```

But I'm damn sure there is a more elegant and faster way of doing it especially when the number of works gets bigger.

Comment: Could the problem be restated as "Display 1 work from the last 12 users who've created one or many works?"

Comment: You could say it like that.  But there's no way I can no from the User model that a user has or hasn't created any works lately.

Comment: What database are you using? Solutions that use more sophisticated SQL are likely to be database-specific.

Comment: Also, for the record, there's a bug in your in-memory implementation: `user_ids` and `works` are initialized to the same `Array`; they should each be initialized to separate `Array`s. Not that it matters if you want a different implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work for any SQL database with minimal adjustment. Whether one thinks it's elegant or not depends on how much you enjoy SQL.

```
def self.latest_works_one_per_user(video_id=nil)
   scope = includes(:user, :video)
   scope = video_id ? scope.where(video_id: video_id) : scope.where.not(video_id: nil)
   scope.
     joins("join (select user_id, max(created_at) created_at
                    from works group by created at) most_recent
                  on works.user_id = most_recent.user_id and
                    works.created_at = most_recent.created_at").
     order(created_at: :desc).limit(12)
end
```

It only works if the combination of user_id and created_at is unique, however. If that combination isn't unique you'll get more than 12 rows.

It can be done more simply in MySQL. The MySQL solution doesn't work in Postgres, and I don't know a better solution in Postgres, although I'm sure there is one.